# How to make a double id field in mysql? Or something like this?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `pdfs` table in mysql with columns: `id, link, creator_id`. I need to make something like tree structure. Now this pdf files can have only 1 version, but I need to be able to make a few versions, but in this case ID should increments after the dot.

E.g. we have an pdf file with `id = 5`. If client wants to edit this pdf, we need to make a new file with id = `5.1`, but mysql cant make a primary key with double/float number. How to do this right way?

P.S. I'll do this project with laravel, that's why I tagged it with `laravel` and `php`

P.S.S. sorry for my bad english, I'm trying to do it better :)

Comment: Have `id`, `version` as two separate columns, then use ``(`id`,`version`)`` as your primary key.

Comment: Should I make an auto_increment for the `version` column?

Comment: @Alexxosipov no, just make a query look up the last version and increment it when you insert a new version

Comment: Then I should do it with php, not with native mysql, am I right?

Comment: The statement: *but mysql cant make a primary key with double/float number* is incorrect.  You can absolutely have a column, with data type `FLOAT`, that also is a primary key.